# Jenkins node throws script.sh: 2: //: Permission denied error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins master that's connected to a node. I'm attempting to execute a pipeline on the master to run a job on the connected node, in node i have some commands to run. However, when I run the pipeline, I encounter the following error:

*/home/ubuntu/workspace/node-pipetest@tmp/durable-87636e52/script.sh: 2: //: Permission denied*

ERROR: script returned exit code 126

This error indicates that there's a permission issue when trying to execute a script on the connected node.  I have updated permission with chmod, full access.  still unable to fix this.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Dev Build') {
      agent { label 'dev-node' }
      steps {
        // shell script follows
        sh '''\
pwd

// If the application is running, kill it
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp

// This is the auto update all the repo updates
sudo apt-get update

// Install maven
sudo apt install -y maven
'''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
Started by user Admin Team
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on qa-node in /home/ubuntu/workspace/node-pipetest
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Dev Build)
[Pipeline] node
Running on dev-node in /home/ubuntu/workspace/node-pipetest
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/workspace/node-pipetest@tmp/
+ // If the application is running, kill it
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node-pipetest@tmp/durable-9d8ad363/script.sh: 5: //: Permission denied
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 126
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Transcribe them into the question.

Comment: [Pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) or of [exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) are not very helpful, they are hard to read, impossible to copy/paste from, practically invisible to screen readers and search engines, and may be hosted on domains that are blocked on some networks. Put a [mcve] and (if applicable) text of the exception in the question itself. The editor has buttons and [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help you format it so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you tried to comment a line in that bash script using `//` and it's complaining that that's not a thing.

Did you mean `#`?

Comment: (indeed, I'd bet dollars to donuts that those double slashes are on line 2!)

Comment: have updated sample pipeline can you check that.

Comment: @MohanBalakrishnan as mentioned in my answer, your quoted string is a bash script not Groovy or pipeline code. `//` is not a comment in bash.